# What is the URL query parameter for EQL in Endeca 5.x?

Tags: endeca

I have to generate an Endeca Url that has an EQL (Nrs) parameter as well, e.g.:
N=200590+82&**Nrs=collection()/record[p_MyProperty<=100+or+p_MyOtherProperty>200]**

I've tried it out on Endeca 6.0 and it perfectly works but our target system is 5.0 which completely ignores the Nrs parameter. Adding or removing this parameter the result set is the same.

Does 5.x uses different syntax for EQL? Or is it a feature from 6.0? Maybe in our Endeca instance this feature is turned off?

Answer (score 0):

The `Nrs` parameter is available in Endeca 5.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feature support document that tells me that EQL was introduced in version 5.1.1.  And specifically not supported in 5.0.

You could try using some features that did work in 5.0.

You could also do some baseline calculations with record filters.  That might give you the intended effect. (Pretty much pre-calculate the ranges you need and select them via record filter.)

Documentation for record filters:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/rbdv_urlparams_nr.html